# How can you read one line string & integer input in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, input, data-structures

Let's say that I have this program that will execute "a" if I input "a" and "b" if I input "b". But they need different things to proceed, like "a" needs 2 input integers and "b" only needs 1 input integer. So, the input will look like this:

```
8 2 // 8 is how many people and 2 is how many actions
a 2 8
b 6
```

How can I code a program that read like that? Like if "a" scan 2 integers, if "b" scan 1 integer. This is what I have right now:

```
int people, action;
char cmd[100];

scanf("%d %d", &people, &action);
for (int i = 0; i < action; i++) {
     scanf("%c", &cmd);
     if (cmd % 97 == 0) {
         #TODO
     } else if (cmd % 98 == 0) {
         #TODO
     }
}
```

But this won't work, the program actually reads a 2 8 b 6 as i loops. Please help me.

Comment: `cmd % 97 == 0` is a very weird and convoluted way of saying `cmd == 'a'`. Please try to use the more readable way, it will benefit everyone attempting to read your code, including yourself.

Comment: As for your problem, in the case of `'a'` just use `scanf` to read two integers, and in the case of `'b'` read one?

Comment: `scanf("%c", &cmd);` this is wrong, do you want to scan a string or a character? if you want to scan a string use the `%s` specifier, if you want to scan a character `char cmd[100];` should be `char cmd;`

Comment: see: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to work with character arrays here. Just simply a single character is all you need, and the for loop you've started from `0 to < action` but not `1 to <= action` you're not working with any arrays here and you can just do it straightforwardly.

Corrections are commented out in the below refined code:

```
int people, action;
char command; // you don't need ...[100]

int a, b, c;

printf("People <sp> Action: ");
scanf("%d %d", &people, &action);

for (int i = 1; i <= action; i++) {
    scanf("%c", &command);

    if (command == 'a') { // use this expression --- (1)
        scanf("%d %d", &a, &b); // asks for two inputs

    } else if (command == 'b') {
        scanf("%d", &c); // asks for one input

    } else {
        // To Do Else
    }
}
```

OR

If you want to work with `int a, b, c` using arrays, then, modify the declaration as follows:

```
int a[MAX], b[MAX], c[MAX]; // const int MAX = your required number
```

And jump to `(1)` section marked in the program, modify something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < action; i++) { // you may use this in this situation
    .
    .
    if (command == 'a')
        scanf("%d %d", &a[i], &b[i]);
    .
    .
}
```

**Note:** You can use `break` statement wherever necessary within the loop (e.g. when `command == 'b' then do TODOS and break;`. It might be helpful to you.

Comment: `scanf("%c", command); // no need of '&'` , yes, you need `&`

Comment: You need the `&` in the first `%c` `scanf`. and warning when you read two character with`scanf` : you will read spaces or line feed.

Comment: But only a single character required to be entered as OP asked and generally using `&` with `scanf()` not used for single char input.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fgets()` for user input

```
int people, action;
char cmd[100];
int p1, p2, args;
char line[1000]; // large enough
if (!fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
if (sscanf(line, "%d%d", &people, &action) != 2) { fprintf(stderr, "bad line\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
for (int k = 0; k < action; k++) {
    if (!fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    if ((args = sscanf(line, "%c%d%d", cmd, &p1, &p2)) < 2) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    switch (*cmd) {
        default: exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        case 'a': case 'A':
            if (args != 3) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            process_a(p1, p2);
            break;
        case 'b': case 'B':
            if (args != 2) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            process_b(p1);
            break;
    }
}
```